# UI for picking a relative time interval

Tags: android, time, uipickerview, timepicker

Is there a nice quick solution for doing this? The user is to select hours:minutes, but this is not a time of day, but rather an interval relative to the present (for example something like this would be used by a stopwatch app). So, TimePicker is perhaps not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing something like this: [image: Android Clock UI]. This is the stock Android clock app.

Comment: How should I do that? Do I just create all the buttons and fields manually?

Comment: Yep, and internally you want to maintain a stack of numbers that you can push and pop from.